# MySQL Datediff syntax

Tags: sql

I've to calculate the difference in days between the current date and a date (dataaction) stored in the database.

I need to know when this difference in days is:

1. <= 30
2. > 30 and <= 60
3. > 60

And I tried this query sql, but the output is wrong because in all the rows the total is not correct.

How to calculate the difference in days when is > 30 and <= 60 ?

```
mysql> SELECT
    IFNULL(action, 'Tot') AS action,
    COUNT(*) AS Tot,
    SUM(

        IF (
            DATEDIFF(
                CURRENT_DATE (),
                dataaction
            ) <= 30,
            1,
            0
        )
    ) '<= 30',
    SUM(

        IF (
            DATEDIFF(
                CURRENT_DATE (),
                dataaction
            ) <= 60,
            1,
            0
        )
    ) '<= 60',
    SUM(

        IF (
            DATEDIFF(
                CURRENT_DATE (),
                dataaction
            ) > 60,
            1,
            0
        )
    ) '> 60'
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `tbl`
    ) t
GROUP BY
    action WITH ROLLUP;
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+
| action     | Tot    | <= 30 | <= 60 | > 60 |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+
| study      |     83 | 7     | 37    | 46   |
| rebuilding |     25 | 25    | 25    | 0    |
| checking   |     95 | 2     | 3     | 92   |
| screening  |     39 | 1     | 4     | 35   |
| Tot        |    242 | 35    | 69    | 173  |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+
5 rows in set

mysql>
```

Comment: switch/case syntax would make this a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments, this is a simple example of switch/case syntax to solve this problem.  It is not an attempt to solve the problem.

```
select 
    case
        when datediff(day, current_date, dataaction) <= 30 then '<= 30'
        when datediff(day, current_date, dataaction) <= 60 then '31 to 60'
        else '> 60' 
    end age_range
    , count(*) records
from 
    etc
group by 
    case
        when datediff(day, current_date, dataaction) <= 30 then '<= 30'
        when datediff(day, current_date, dataaction) <= 60 then '31 to 60'
        else '> 60' 
    end
```

Comment: In the `group by` clause you can simply put `age_range`... In `group by` and `having` clauses you can use column aliases

Comment: I don't use mysql and did not realize that it allowed the use of aliases in the group by clause.